# Epson epos javascript sdk connection error when printing - TM T82III

Tags: javascript, printing, sdk, epson, epos

Using Epson epos javascript sdk, getting "Connection Refused" error if the printer ip address is not opened in the browser url. Once it is opened receipt printing will work for the day, the next day when I try to print the  Connection Refused message will appear again unless I open the printer ip address. Am I missing any configuration settings in EposNet config?
printer: Epson TM-T82III Ethernet printer

```
function connect() {
  var printerPort = document.getElementById("printer_port").value;
  var printerAddress = document.getElementById("printer_ip").value;
  ePosDev = new epson.ePOSDevice();
  ePosDev.connect(printerAddress, printerPort, cbConnect, { "eposprint": true });
}
function cbConnect(data) {
  if (data == 'OK' || data == 'SSL_CONNECT_OK') {
    var deviceID = document.getElementById("printer_name").value;
    ePosDev.createDevice(deviceID, ePosDev.DEVICE_TYPE_PRINTER, { 'crypto': true, 'buffer': false }, cbCreateDevice_printer);
  } else {
   alert(data);// 'error parameter'
  }
}
```